# (gspread) How can I put a custom formula into a cell using gspread?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

I want to put a custom formula into a sheet using gspread. This can be done in Google Sheets and [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imp1U.png).

I want to automate the process of inputting this using gspread, similar to how you can use batch_update to format multiple cells, I would like to use it to add a custom formula to multiple cells.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `put a custom formula into a cell` and your showing image. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: In Google Sheets you can set the conditional formatting rules of a range of cells. One of the rules can be a custom formula. I want to know how to set a cells custom formula using gspread.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Its okay, I will try to explain it more simply. The base of my question is how to do formatting rules using gspread. Do you know what a formatting rule is in Google Sheets?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. I cannot understand your goal from `The base of my question is how to do formatting rules using gspread.`. By this, I cannot answer to `Do you know what a formatting rule is in Google Sheets?`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: An example of conditional formatting is like this. A cell is colored red, however if the value inside has a value greater than 5, it will color itself blue instead.

A conditional format will apply if the condition is true. In the example, the condition was for the cell to have a value greater than 5. Once the condition is met, the conditional formatting is applied. This can already be done in Google Sheets by right clicking a cell and then clicking, "Conditional Formatting", however I would like to do this using gspread.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. For example, do you want to set the conditional format rule to multiple cells? Or, do you want to put a function to multiple cells? Or, do you want to set the background colors to multiple cells?

Comment: Hello, I want to set the conditional format rule to multiple cells. Preferably using the batch_update function, if possible

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I want to set the conditional format rule to multiple cells.`, can you provide the detail setting of the conditional format rule you want to use?

Comment: Hello. The specific conditional format rule I want to use is a custom formula. The formula is as follows: `=indirect("Sheet1!B2")<>"hello"` The formatting style that applies is to set the color of the cell to white.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your reply, you want to put the conditional formatting rule of `=indirect("Sheet1!B2")<>"hello"` and when this is true, you want to set the background color to white. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, where cells do you want to put them?

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me with this. Yes, you are absolutely correct. The cells I would like to put them in is every cell in a worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create the conditional formatting rule of `=indirect("Sheet1!B2")<>"hello"` and when this is true, you want to set the background color to white.
- You want to create the conditional formatting rule for all cells in a sheet of Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread for python.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("Sheet2") # Please set your sheet name.

formula = '=indirect("Sheet1!B2")<>"hello"'
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addConditionalFormatRule": {
                "index": 0,
                "rule": {
                    "ranges": [{"sheetId": sheet.id}],
                    "booleanRule": {
                        "condition": {
                            "type": "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
                            "values": [{"userEnteredValue": formula}],
                        },
                        "format": {
                            "backgroundColorStyle": {
                                "rgbColor": {"red": 1, "green": 1, "blue": 1}
                            }
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

- When this script is run, the above `addConditionalFormatRule` is created for all cells in "Sheet2". When `Sheet1!B2` is not `hello`, the background color of all cells of "Sheet2" is white.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/spreadsheet.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addconditionalformatrulerequest)

### Added:

About your following reply,

> I've modified my script based off of yours and it works perfect. I just want to know if its possible to have a list of conditional format rules that can be created for separate cells. Is this possible?

Your expected goal is the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet2" # Please set your sheet name.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
sheetId = sheet.id
service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=client.auth)
res = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, ranges=sheetName, fields="sheets(properties(gridProperties(rowCount,columnCount)))").execute()

row = res["sheets"][0]["properties"]["gridProperties"]["rowCount"]
column = res["sheets"][0]["properties"]["gridProperties"]["columnCount"]

formula = '=indirect("Sheet1!B2")<>"hello"'
requests = []
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(column):
        requests.append(
            {
                "addConditionalFormatRule": {
                    "index": 0,
                    "rule": {
                        "ranges": [
                            {
                                "sheetId": sheetId,
                                "startRowIndex": i,
                                "endRowIndex": i + 1,
                                "startColumnIndex": j,
                                "endColumnIndex": j + 1,
                            }
                        ],
                        "booleanRule": {
                            "condition": {
                                "type": "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
                                "values": [{"userEnteredValue": formula}],
                            },
                            "format": {
                                "backgroundColorStyle": {
                                    "rgbColor": {"red": 1, "green": 1, "blue": 1}
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    },
                }
            }
        )
spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests})
```

- In this case, in order to retrieve the values of row and column of the sheet, googleapis for python is used. So, please add `from googleapiclient.discovery import build`.
- When this script is run, `addConditionalFormatRule` is create in all cells of "Sheet2". But, I thought that this is the same result with the above script.
- **PLESE BE CAREFUL**

  - When this script is run, `addConditionalFormatRule` is create in all cells of "Sheet2". So, for example, when the default sheet is used, a lot of conditional formatting rules are created in all cells of 1000 rows x 26 columns. Please be careful about this.
  - If you want to limit the cells, please manually set `row` and `column`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I've modified my script based off of yours and it works perfect. I just want to know if its possible to have a list of conditional format rules that can be created for separate cells. Is this possible?

Comment: @Alfredo Lozano Jr About `I just want to know if its possible to have a list of conditional format rules that can be created for separate cells.`, I think that my proposed sample script achieves this. How about this? If I misunderstood your question, I have to apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? And, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: My goal is to have a loop that assigns conditional format rules to different cells. Your solution sets the same conditional format rule to all cells within a sheet.

Comment: @Alfredo Lozano Jr Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!! I've rewritten my code using your script and I am finally satisfied. Thank you very much. Your new script does do the same as the original, however the new script allows me to modify the formula to be different depending on the cell by using the format() function. Thank you again Tanaike. You are very good at using gspread.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED'` parameter on your sheet update. This will basically input into the spreadsheet call like you input it manually yourself. View more here, https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption

with sheets api:

```
sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=auth.get_credentials())
response = sheets_service.spreadsheets().values().update(
                spreadsheetId='<ENTER SPREADSHEET ID HERE>', range='<ENTER CELL RANGE HERE>', 
                valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body='<YOUR CUSTOM FORMULA HERE>').execute()
```

with gspread:

```
sh.values_update(
    'Sheet1!A2',
    params={
        'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'
    },
    body={
        'values': ...
    }
)
```

https://docs.gspread.org/en/v3.7.0/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_update

Comment: sorry, didn't know what gspread was. I believe 'valueInputOption' parameter is available on gspread as well.

Comment: Its okay, so will this not work with gspread? Im not exactly sure how to use this in my code.